# The sufficient condition for a function equals to zero when it vanishes in an open set

Tags: real-analysis

For the class od analytic functions in one variable, there is an identity theorem: "*If two holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ on a domain $D$ agree on a set $S$ which has an accumulation point $c$ in $D$, i.e. $f = g$ on $S\subseteq D$, then $f = g$ on $D$*".
 For continuous functions, this is not true, thus I wonder: is there some additional condition(s) I can use to define a class of continuous function for which some kind of uniqueness theorem holds?

For example, consider a function series
$$
f(a)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}c_j a^{ib_j},
$$
where

- $a\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$, $b_j\in \mathbb{R}$ and
- $c_j\in \mathbb{C}$ and satisfies the following growth condition
  $$
  |c_j|<\frac{(n+1)^{\delta}}{n^3},\quad 0<\delta<1
  $$ when $0<n<b_j<n+1$.

If $f(a)=0$ on the set $\big\{a\in \Bbb R\;|\;0<|a|<a_0\big\}$, then does it equal to zero for every $a\in \Bbb R$? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: The Denjoy-Carleman theorem states that if $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$ and the derivatives $f^{(n)}$ do not grow too quickly, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. In particular, if $f|_U=0$ for some open set $U$, then $f=0$ everywhere.

Comment: A class of functions with this property is called quasianalytic. Many quasianalytic classes were studied in the literature, the most known is the Denjoy-Carleman class from the previous remark. But there are many other types of conditions which imply this sort of uniqueness.

Comment: For Denjoy-Carleman see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function#The_Denjoy–Carleman_theorem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be answered by a fairly well known theorem, mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Do you think Carleman theorem can prove the function given in the question to be quasi-analytic? I try to prove it and find maybe it is not in the Denjoy-Carleman class. Could you give some idea about it if it is in the Denjoy-Carleman class. @MarkWildon